# Is it possible to call a relative address with each instruction at most 3 bytes long, in 32-bit mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, machine-code

I'm working on **an exercise** in x86 assembly (using NASM) that has the niche requirement of **limiting each instruction to a maximum of 3 bytes**.

I'd like to call a label, but the normal way to do this (shown in the code example) always results in an instruction size of 5 bytes. I'm trying to find out if there's a series of instructions, 3 bytes or less each, that can accomplish this.

I've attempted to load the label address into a register and then call that register, but it seems like the address is then interpreted as an absolute address, instead of a relative one.

I looked around to see if there's a way to force call to interpret the address in the register as a relative address, but couldn't find anything. I have thought about simulating a call by pushing a return address to the stack and using `jmp rel8`, but am unsure how to get the absolute address of where I want to return to.

Here is the normal way to do what I want:

```
[BITS 32]

call func     ; this results in a 5-byte call rel32 instruction
; series of instructions here that I would like to return to

func:
  ; some operations here
  ret
```

I have tried things like this:

```
[BITS 32]

mov eax, func          ; 5-byte  mov r32, imm32
call eax               ; 2-byte  call r32
          ; this fails, seems to interpret func's relative address as an absolute
 ...   ; series of instructions here that I would like to return to

func:
  ; some operations here
  ret
```

I have a feeling there may be a way to do this using some sort of LEA magic, but I'm relatively new to assembly so I couldn't figure it out.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: `mov eax, func; call func` indeed uses absolute address but that should still work. Unless you load the code elsewhere than where it was assembled for. In that case you want position independent code. However `mov eax, func` will again be 5 bytes exceeding your limit.

Comment: There is no such thing as relative indirect near call.

Comment: In 32 bit mode the usual trick to get the current EIP for position independence unfortunately relies on a `call` that is exactly the one you want to avoid. Depending on your exact requirements and environment (e.g. executable stack) you can cheat by creating longer instructions dynamically :)

Comment: Also the 16 bit call which would fit in 3 bytes unfortunately zeroes the top 16 bits of EIP, it does not simply limit the offset to 16 bits which would work for us. And you'd need a prefix so that would again be more than 3 bytes. Eh.

Comment: What is the requirement about instructions being 3 bytes or less for?

Comment: @MichaelPetch The concept behind the instruction size limit came from an old university practice set I found online, I expanded on it a bit and ran into this problem. Was just curious if it is in fact (realistically) impossible to accomplish.

Comment: How will this code be assembled and built? Is this targeting Linux?

Comment: `mov eax, func` ; `call eax` is correct.  If that doesn't work (after linking), you're building your code wrong.  Related (maybe duplicate): **[Shorter x86 call instruction](//stackoverflow.com/q/49700798)** - `mov eax, func` is a win when amortized over two 2-byte `call eax` instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes :  `mov eax, func` is a 5 byte instruction. The OP is doing this where the maximum instruction size is 3 bytes. This question isn't a duplicate of the one you show. The OP isn't trying to find the shortest encoding, but an encoding where no one instruction exceeds a 3 byte encoding but still can call a function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's code golf.

Comment: @gaskini:  I don't understand your reasoning for saying `call eax` fails.  Obviously `mov eax, immediate` is only encodeable as 5-byte `mov r32, imm32`.  After putting the absolute address into a register, of course `call` needs to be absolute.  (And that's all x86 has available).  I edited your example to comment the instruction lengths.  What's missing is a 3-byte encoding for `lea r32, [EIP + rel8]` (because there's no such addressing mode, and 32-bit mode doesn't have PC-relative address generation other than call).

Comment: I don't think a `call` with a rel32 (instead of an address) in a register would be useful for anything outside of this code-golf problem, and you'd still have to generate the relative offset in a register somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as relative indirect near [`CALL`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call). You will have to find some other mechanism to do the call to the label `func`. One method I can think of is building the absolute address in a register and doing an absolute indirect call through the register:

[image]

It is unclear what the target of your code is. This assumes you are generating a 32-bit Linux program. I use a linker script to compute the individual bytes of the target label. Those bytes will be used by the program to build a return address in *EAX* and then an indirect near call via *EAX* will be performed. A couple methods of building the address are presented.

A linker script `link.ld` that breaks a label's address into individual bytes:

```
SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x8048000;
  func_b0 =  func & 0x000000ff;
  func_b1 = (func & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
  func_b2 = (func & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
  func_b3 = (func & 0xff000000) >> 24;
}
```

Assembly code file `myprog.asm`:

```
[BITS 32]
global func
extern func_b0, func_b1, func_b2, func_b3

_start:
    ; Method 1
    mov al, func_b3            ; EAX = ######b3
    mov ah, func_b2            ; EAX = ####b2b3
    bswap eax                  ; EAX = b3b2####
    mov ah, func_b1            ; EAX = b3b2b1##
    mov al, func_b0            ; EAX = b3b2b1b0
    call eax

    ; Method 2
    mov ah, func_b3            ; EAX = ####b3##
    mov al, func_b2            ; EAX = ####b3b2
    shl eax, 16                ; EAX = b3b20000
    mov ah, func_b1            ; EAX = b3b2b100
    mov al, func_b0            ; EAX = b3b2b1b0
    call eax

    ; series of instructions here that I would like to return to
    xor eax, eax
    mov ebx, eax               ; EBX = 0 return value
    inc eax                    ; EAX = 1 exit system call
    int 0x80                   ; Do exit system call

func:
    ; some operations here
    ret
```

Assemble and link with:

```
nasm -f elf32 -F dwarf myprog.asm -o myprog.o
gcc -m32 -nostartfiles -g -Tlink.ld myprog.o -o myprog
```

If you run `objdump -Mintel -Dx` the information of interest would look something similar to:

> ```
> 00000020 g       *ABS*  00000000 func_b0
> 00000004 g       *ABS*  00000000 func_b2
> 08048020 g       .text  00000000 func
> 00000080 g       *ABS*  00000000 func_b1
> 00000008 g       *ABS*  00000000 func_b3
>
> ...
>
> 08048000 <_start>:
>  8048000:       b0 08                   mov    al,0x8
>  8048002:       b4 04                   mov    ah,0x4
>  8048004:       0f c8                   bswap  eax
>  8048006:       b4 80                   mov    ah,0x80
>  8048008:       b0 20                   mov    al,0x20
>  804800a:       ff d0                   call   eax
>  804800c:       b4 08                   mov    ah,0x8
>  804800e:       b0 04                   mov    al,0x4
>  8048010:       c1 e0 10                shl    eax,0x10
>  8048013:       b4 80                   mov    ah,0x80
>  8048015:       b0 20                   mov    al,0x20
>  8048017:       ff d0                   call   eax
>  8048019:       31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
>  804801b:       89 c3                   mov    ebx,eax
>  804801d:       40                      inc    eax
>  804801e:       cd 80                   int    0x80
>
> 08048020 <func>:
>  8048020:       c3                      ret
> ```

Answer (score 4):

In 32-bit x86, the only way to read your current instruction pointer is to do a `call` instruction and read the stack.  Unless you have the address of a suitable gadget already in a register, you will have to use an immediate relative offset, which is a 5-byte instruction.

(In 64-bit x86, you can also use `lea rax, [rip]`, but that is a 7-byte instruction.)

However, it might be possible to cheat here.  If the code that calls your NASM binary always calls your code with something like `call edi`, then you can just calculate from that register.  It's a hack, but so is restricting yourself to 3-byte instructions.

By the way, for a little trick, this is how you can load 32-bit constants in 3-byte (or 2-byte) instructions (loading 0xDEADBEEF as an example):

```
mov al, 0xDE
mov ah, 0xAD
bswap eax
mov ah, 0xBE
mov al, 0xEF
```

Comment: Not the *only* way to read EIP.  The only sane way yes, but if you're running in kernel mode then an `int` instruction will push a return address onto the stack for you.  And you can create an interrupt handler that returns that address using only small instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Just thought of another way: on a 64-bit OS, `sysret` used by the kernel requires the return address be in `rcx`. Do a system call that the kernel ends with `sysret` instead of `iretq`, then read `rcx`.  Crazy but effective.

Answer (score 1):

**In 64-bit code**, [2-byte `syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) will set RCX = RIP (which the kernel usually uses for `sysret`), so under most OSes you can make an invalid system call to get RCX=RIP.  (e.g. by setting EAX or RAX to -1 with 3-byte `or eax,-1`, so under Linux `syscall` will return with RAX = -ENOSYS.)  [Credit to @Myria for this idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261594/is-it-possible-to-call-a-relative-address-with-each-instruction-at-most-3-bytes/57264239?noredirect=1#comment101053121_57261976)

It depends on the OS whether this method works: an OS can always return with `iret` after doing anything it wants to the registers, so it would be possible to design a kernel ABI where this doesn't work.  But AFAIK it should work under any of the mainstream OSes.  But again, only in long mode. 
 AMD CPUs support `syscall` in 32-bit mode but it works differently.

---

**In 32-bit code, the only normal/sane way to read EIP is with a `call` instruction.**  So it's generally impossible to create position-independent code without using 5-byte `call rel32` to get your own address.

(Even self-modifying code would eventually *execute* a `call rel32`).

Other answers show ways to jump to a given *absolute* address using only small instructions.  But the target address isn't relative to the address of the machine code, except insofar as the absolute address of the machine code is *also* known so you can calculate the jump distance at build time.

The same machine code would jump to the *same* address if loaded somewhere else, not to the same offset *relative* to its own address.

Perhaps that's all your exercise was asking for.

---

If not, **since we've rules out sane ways to write fully-PIC code, we need to consider insane ways.**

**Interrupts also push EIP onto the (kernel) stack, where an interrupt handler could access it.**

If you're writing a kernel that can include interrupt handlers, you can include one that puts your current address into a register (for example EAX) by reading it from the stack with short instructions (like 3-byte `mov eax, [ebp+4]` or whatever after setting up a stack-frame).

Then your normal code can invoke that interrupt handler with `int 0x81` or whatever (a 3-byte instruction).

Setting up an interrupt-descriptor table should be possible if necessary: we can construct any value in registers using `mov r8,imm8` and shifts as shown in other answer.  Using this + 2 or 3-byte `mov r/m32, r32` or 3-byte `mov r/m8, imm8` we can store anything to any absolute address we choose by constructing the address (and optionally value) in a register.  This is setup to facilitate being able to run code that queries its own address with a compact "system call" instead of a `call rel32`.

Actually installing an IDT is possible with 3-byte `lidt` (`0F 01 /3` with a simple addressing mode that uses ModRM + no extra byte).  Or  query the current location with `sidt` (same-length encoding).

`iret` is just 1-byte `0xCF`.  I don't think any of the necessary system-setup instructions have a minimum length of more than 3 bytes.

Comment: How do you get the address of the handler to put into the IDT?

Comment: @prl: you choose a fixed constant address for the handler itself, and for the IDT.  This infrastructure then supports PIC code, but is not itself PIC.